# Is it safe to put params in a flash notice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Here's my action code in my controller.

```
def index
  if params[:writer]
    if Article.published.where('writer = ?', params[:writer]).count < 1
      redirect_to articles_url, :notice => "There are no articles by #{params[:writer]}"
    else
      @articles = Article.published.where('writer = ?', params[:writer]).order('published_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
    end
  else
    @articles = Article.published.order('published_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
  end
end
```

I think the question is fairly obvious. In some simple testing Rails seems to escape that `:notice` just fine, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't asking for trouble by doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fine.  Rails 3 escapes HTML when by default when you display it via <%= %>

If you ever need it unescaped you would display it as

```
<%= flash.html_safe %>
```